# Is there any aggregation equivalent to fuzzy search in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch, I can achieve like query search using Fuzzy query. Is there any filter or aggregation to support the same?

example of fuzzy search :

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.fuzzyQuery("name", "userNsme");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [query filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-filter.html) to filter by a fuzzy query.

```
{
    "filter": {
        "query": {
            "fuzzy": {
                "name": "userNsme"
            }
        }
    }
}
```